# Formula referencing last row VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm passing a bunch of concatenated data into an ODBC workbook via a single Excel cell. The cell changes based on the number of rows in the data. To manage this, I want to insert a formula into a second cell (using VBA) that looks something like this...

```
With Sheets("MAIN")
LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With    

Sheets("MAIN").Range("A1").Formula = "=("B" & LastRow)"
```

This code doesn't work. I think it's close, but I'm a hack. Can any of you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Sheets("MAIN").Range("A1").Formula = "=B" & LastRow
```

---

And, if this is the entire code in this section of your application, it would be good (although definitely not required) to include the last line within the `With` block, i.e.

```
With Sheets("MAIN")
    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1").Formula = "=B" & LastRow
End With
```

Comment: You're very helpful. Thank you!